# Запрос для Яндекса

Tags: c#

Всем привет, скажите, вот я читаю книги по C#, но там мало уделяют времени работе системы, т.е., к примеру, я хочу написать типа свой диспетчер задач, но мне нужно знать, как работать с системой, хочу найти книгу в яндексе, но дело в том, что я не могу правильно придумать запрос.

Answer (score 1):

[Common Intermediate Language и системное программирование в Microsoft. NET](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2623162/) есть еще [издание 2010 года](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5322020/).